# Atributos em funções - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estava observando que o `$` do jQuery é uma função, mas se eu fizer `$.` eu consigo acessar varias outras funções, que são atributos da função `$`. Como é possível uma funcão ter atributos que são acessíveis fora do contexto através do `.`?

Comment: Como assim acessíveis fora do contexto?

Comment: Acho que você devia era analisar as suas outras perguntas que possuem respostas e nenhuma foi marcada como resolvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fizer isso já vai funcionar:

```js
function Guilherme() {
    console.log('Chamou o Foo');
}

Guilherme.falar = function (msg) {
     console.log('Guilherme diz:', msg);
};

Guilherme();

Guilherme.falar('olá mundo');
Guilherme.falar('Tchau!');
```

Isto ocorre porque quando você usa a *expressão `function`* o JavaScript cria um objeto, em JavaScript é praticamente tudo acessivel como objeto (depois vou melhorar essa parte da explicação).

Você também pode criar um objeto simples com `prototype` seria como classes em outras linguagens (não vou falar de ES6 agora porque vai fugir da intenção da pergunta), por exemplo um exemplo de um "jQuery proprio seu", assim:

```js
(function () {
    function $(seletor) {
       //Checa se é um objeto
       if (this instanceof $) {
           this.elementos = document.querySelectorAll(seletor);
           this.length = this.elementos.length;
       } else {
          //Se chamar `new $` vai direto, se chamar $() então a propria função instancia o objeto e retorna ele
          return new $(seletor);
       }
    }

    $.prototype = {
        "length": 0,
        "html": function () {
             if (this.length) return this.elementos[0].innerHTML;
        },
        "text": function () {
             if (this.length) return this.elementos[0].textContent;
        }
    };

    window.$ = $;
})();

console.log("html retornado:", $("#test").html() );
console.log("texto retornado:",  $("#test").text() );
```

```html
<div id="test">
Olá mundo <b>novo</b>!
</div>
```

---

Se você quer "estender" tipos de objetos existentes, como `String` ou `Number`, você pode usar `.prototype`, assim terá acesso ao `this` e poderá pegar o valor:

```js
String.prototype.foobar = function () {
     console.log('String.foobar pegou:', this);
};

Number.prototype.foobar = function () {
     console.log('Number.foobar pegou:', this);
};

var testestr = "exemplo de string";
var testenum = 2018;

testestr.foobar();
testenum.foobar();
```

Comment: No segundo exemplo você está sobrescrevendo a função `Guilherme` com o objeto.

Comment: @bfavaretto desculpe, sono, apaguei o prototype xD

Comment: Melhor ir dormir e rever amanhã rs. <strike>Porque esse segundo bloco continua com problema, os métodos do prototype só seriam acessíveis por instâncias geradas pelo uso como construtor.</strike> A pergunta é complicada, dá margem a muitos temas relacionados mas diferentes, melhor burilar sua resposta com calma depois.

Comment: @bfavaretto exato, hehehe, com certeza estou confuso, vou remover e no futuro vejo de onde tirei isso :) obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript as funções têm semelhanças a objetos. A palavra "atributos" não é correta aqui, mas sim "propriedades", e portanto as funções podem ter propriedades que no caso de elas serem funções se chamam "métodos".

Assim podes criar uma função com o nome que quiseres, incluíndo com o nome de `$` como o jQuery fez. Depois podes juntar propriedades ou métodos a essa função específica (a essa *instância* específica) ou ao protótipo de uma função, o que faz com que esses métodos e propriedades fiquem disponíveis em todas as funções desse protótipo.

Repara no exemplo onde crio duas funções, e maneiras diferentes de lhes adicionar propriedades e como adicionar propriedades "globalmente" a todas as funções

```js
// declaração da função
function $_$(seletor) {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(seletor)];
}

// declaração de outra função
function qqCoisa() {
  return 'Qualquer coisa...';
}

// adicionar uma propriedade à instância
$_$.descricao = 'Uma função minha...';

console.log($_$.descricao); // Uma função minha...
console.log(qqCoisa.descricao); // "undefined" - nada, esta função não tem esta propriedade

Function.prototype.metodoGlobal = function() {
  return 'Eu sou global...';
}

console.log($_$.metodoGlobal()); // Eu sou global...
console.log(qqCoisa.metodoGlobal()); // Eu sou global...
```

O que acontece no jQuery é que se cria uma instância única, mais específica, que recebe uma série de métodos. E para poderes ter o contexto interno (usar o `this` e dar-lhe valores que só afetam essa instância)  tens de usar o construtor de funções `new`.

Exemplo:

```js
const $_$ = (function() {

  // defenição da função principal que retorna a instância para se poder usar outros métodos encadeados
  function $_$_proto(seletor) {
    this.conteudo = [...document.querySelectorAll(seletor)];
    return this;
  }

  // um método adicionado ao protótipo para que todas as intâncias venham com ele
  $_$_proto.prototype.buscarTags = function() {
    return this.conteudo.map(el => el.tagName.toLowerCase());
  }

  // a função "fábrica" que retorna uma nova instância (com o seu "this" único) para se poder consumir
  return function(seletor) {
    return new $_$_proto(seletor);
  }
})();


console.log($_$('.teste').buscarTags()); // ["div", "p"]
```

```html
<div class="teste">Uma div</div>
<p class="teste">Um p</p>
```